# How to avoid large matrix allocation

Tags: r, matrix, memory

I have two arrays of n elements (arrays p and q):

```
p1 p2 p3 ...
q1 q2 q3 ...
```

At first calculate, I should calculate

```
p1*q1+p2*q2
```

At second:

```
p1*q1+p2*q2+p3*q3+p4*q4
```

At third:

```
p1*q1+p2*q2+p3*q3+p4*q4+p5*q5+p6*q6
```

and so on, for k times. These can be view as products between row vector and column vector, so I tried to use the matrix multiplication:

```
Mat<-t(replicate(k, p))
Mat[col(Mat)>2*row(Mat)] <- 0
Res<-Mat%*%q
```

Nevertheless, the size of matrix Mat must be too large, because I obtain

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 27.7 Mb
```

Probably I could solve that problem using `bigmemory` package, as suggested by several posts on this forum, but I wonder if there is a way to simplify my idea. For example, I observe that with matrix `Mat` we allocate several entries which we don't use (the 0s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
set.seed(1)
p = sample(1:5,100,replace=T)
q = sample(1:5,100,replace=T)

# my initial idea was the following, but that contains a lot of redundant calculations...
sapply(1:length(p), function(x) {sum(head(q,x)*head(p,x))})

# a lot simpler:
cumsum(p*q)
```

first element is `p[1]*q[1]`, second element is `p[1]*q[1] + p[2]*q[2]`, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you can also extract even elements within the same line, `cumsum(p*q)[c(FALSE,TRUE)]`

Comment: Ah, I missed the requirement of obtaining only even elements, that's a nice solution for that!